# In JDO/DataNucleus can I query for a Joda-Time DateTime object?

Tags: java, jodatime, datanucleus

I see that DataNucleus supports org.joda.DateTime

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jdo/types.html

But does this mean I can index this field and perform queries against this time field, such as "where jodaTimeField > yesterday"?

Or is it only that it can be stored without needing to resort to serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JodaTime types operate in JDOQL like any other Java type. Tests exist (used against RDBMS)
http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/test/accessplatform/trunk/test.jdo.jodatime/src/test/org/datanucleus/tests/QueryTest.java?revision=10387&view=markup

Never tried against other datastore types